# server side javascript REACT JS how to pass ssl certificates

Tags: javascript, rest, ssl

I have reactjs frontend application. 
To implement auth, I am calling another REST web service as POST and json simple request as:

```
{
  "username":"value",
  "password":"value"
}
```

Obviously, I must have ssl for my frontend. Which is fine. 
But, since I have to call another REST web service, I should pass client certificate, otherwise its not connecting and gives error as : TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. Unless I hit auth service url once and say "proceed", not good for other folks to use my UI.

I need to have server side javascript for callign this auth web service. For that I have used express.

My question is, when I make fetch call, how do I pass location of my ssl certificate.

Something similar to curl --cacert option.